# Logstash convert String to timestamp and override @timestamp not working

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, timestamp, logstash, kibana

I have a Variable Grok variable "%{GREEDYDATA:LastBeginDateTime1}", where LastBeginDateTime1 has a datetime format 2018-03-01 13:00:00

I need to convert it to @timestamp variable which I can use in Kibana

My logstash config is like

```
    date
            {
                    match => ["Batch_LastBeginDateTime1", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
                    target => "@timestamp"

            }
```

Can you please assist? Thanks a lot

Comment: Looks fine to me, can you try changing YYYY to yyyy?

Comment: Yeah it's lowercase yyyy